# Are object members thread safe for Callable & ExecutorService

Tags: java, thread-safety, executorservice

Are the members of an object thread-safe if I pass the same object to different Callables and then to a ExecutorService? In my example the classifier has the properties training data, test data and network. All are used within the call() method of the Callable by calling methods of classifier. The same classifier object is passed the each Callable.

```
   for (int i = 0; i < this.cvCount; i++) 
   {
     classifier.setTrainingsData(getTrainingSet(i, testSize));
     classifier.setTestData(getTestSet(i, testSize));
     Callable<XVErrors> callable = new ClassifierCallable<Classifier>(classifier);
     Future<XVErrors> t = this.executor.submit(callable);
     this.results.add(t);
   }
```

... in the ClassifierCallable

```
public XVErrors call() throws Exception {
        XVErrors xv = new XVErrors();
        xv.addTrainingError(classifier.train()); 
        xv.addTestError(classifier.test());
        return xv;
    }
```

I have the feeling I'd have to do a deep copy of the classifier object and pass it on, because when I debug e.g. the train() method the network error is different after I finished the training (tmp and tmp2 are different).

```
public TrainingError train{...

do {
    trainingAlgorithm.iteration();
    epoch++;
    double tmp = trainingAlgorithm.getError();
} while (tmp > trainingErrorThreshold);

double tmp2 = trainingAlgorithm.getError();
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your object is implemented, obviously enough.  If you expect your object to be accessed by multiple threads, then it's your responsibility to figure out how to make those accesses thread-safe.

Comment: So as mentioned I should create new classifier objects for each Callable, if I want them to be processed independently. Otherwise the threads will modify the same object members.

Comment: Depends on your objects!  If you can make them thread-safe for your needs, then do that, if you can't, then copy them.  We can't really answer that question unless you tell us more about your use case.